# Synchronization of Cloud Blobs with the local files

Tags: c#, azure, synchronization, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In a desktop application im developing, I would like to have a feature to store and sync the local save files. Basically, I would like to have a sync button (or automatic when the program starts) that does the following:

- Download all the blobs(files) in the azure storage account that are newer than the local file, or not existent inside the local save folder.
- Upload all the files in the local save folder that are newer than the azure storage blob, or if they are not present on the storage account.

Basically, I want both the local folder and the storage account to have the same files when the syncing is over; but only keeping the newer versions.

To do this, I first tried comparing them by their DateTime; which is working with one exception. Everytime I sync, due to time it takes to upload/download their DateTime's are off by couple of seconds. Therefore, either the local version or the cloud version appears to be newer than the other one always; leading the program to find something to sync everytime the sync button is pressed. I can always put a time threshold when we compare, but that doesn't sound like a valid solution.

Is there a way to make this work through time comparison? Or is there a way to compare the actual files and see if the file has changed? Or any other solution?

Note: Using File.GetLastWriteTime() to get the local file's time, and getting the "Last-Modified" header from the response for the storage blob's date. And using DateTime.Compare() to compare them.

Comment: Azure Blob storage has no sync capability built-in (nor is there something to automatically let you know a blob has just changed, aside from polling/scanning for updates); this will be up to you to implement. You'll probably want to store some sort of metadata somewhere to help you out. Maybe store hashes of files, to know if files are different. Etc. But really... there's no single right way to do it.

Answer (score -2):

You can probably complement the date with the use of the Etag property. This property is updated at each blob modification.

Here is an article that presents the use of Etag for managing blobs:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/managing-concurrency-in-microsoft-azure-storage-2/

You can find more details on headers for blob service, that can help you perform the synchronization:
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/rest/api/storageservices/specifying-conditional-headers-for-blob-service-operations

Comment: ETag won't help you sync, as it's only for determining that something changed blob-side. Won't help you at all, knowing if content is different between local and blob. You'd still need something to compare between local and blob, and still need to track changes with specific metadata to help identify changes.